# Deleted the kernel and unable to recover it

Tags: grub2, kernel

I have accidentally deleted the kernel that I was using (`linux-image-3.5.0-27-generic`) and after rebooting the system it didn't boot anymore. Fortunately I still have some of the old kernels (`linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic`) there and can boot from them.

So I read a little about it and re-installed the `linux-image-generic`, `linux-image-extra-3.5.0-27-generic` and `linux-image-3.5.0-27-generic`, and finally updated grub using `sudo update-grub`. Everything seems to be done correctly and my grub menu list looks like

```
title           Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-27-generic
uuid            1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
kernel          /vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro quiet splash
initrd          /initrd.img-3.5.0-27-generic

title           Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-27-generic (recovery mode)
uuid            1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
kernel          /vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro  single
initrd          /initrd.img-3.5.0-27-generic

title           Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-26-generic
uuid            1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
kernel          /vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro quiet splash
initrd          /initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic

title           Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-26-generic (recovery mode)
uuid            1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
kernel          /vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro  single
initrd          /initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic

title           Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-17-generic
uuid            1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
kernel          /vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro quiet splash
initrd          /initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic

title           Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-17-generic (recovery mode)
uuid            1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
kernel          /vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro  single
initrd          /initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic

title           Ubuntu 12.10, memtest86+
uuid            1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
kernel          /memtest86+.bin
```

But when I reboot the computer the grub menu looks like the old one, i.e. has the previous versions that I have deleted still listed, and also when I try to boot to the latest kernel (`3.5.0.27`) it halts and never boots.

Is there something that I've done wrong or are there some more things I need to do?

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple disks and/or grub installs and the updated one isn't the one being used.  Add the results of this script to your question: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Comment: I just reinstalled grub and updated it again and it solved the issue. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the grub and updated it and it resolved the issue!

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install grub2
sudo update-grub
```

The output of the above script is:

```
     Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


 ============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

  => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
     the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
     in partition 72 for .

 sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

     File system:       ntfs
     Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
     Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
     Operating System:  
     Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

 sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

     File system:       ntfs
     Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
     Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
     Operating System:  
     Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

 sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

     File system:       ntfs
     Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
     Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
     Operating System:  
     Boot files:        

 sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

     File system:       Extended Partition
     Boot sector type:  -
     Boot sector info: 

 sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

     File system:       ext4
     Boot sector type:  -
     Boot sector info: 
     Operating System:  
     Boot files:        /grub/menu.lst /grub/grub.cfg

 sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

     File system:       ext4
     Boot sector type:  -
     Boot sector info: 
     Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.10
     Boot files:        /etc/fstab

 sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

     File system:       swap
     Boot sector type:  -
     Boot sector info: 

 sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

     File system:       ext4
     Boot sector type:  -
     Boot sector info: 
     Operating System:  
     Boot files:        

 sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

     File system:       ext4
     Boot sector type:  -
     Boot sector info: 
     Operating System:  
     Boot files:        

 ============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

 Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

 Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
 Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

 Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

 /dev/sda1    *          2,048     3,074,047     3,072,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
 /dev/sda2           3,074,048   198,386,547   195,312,500   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
 /dev/sda3         592,371,712   625,139,711    32,768,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
 /dev/sda4         198,387,710   592,371,711   393,984,002   5 Extended
 /dev/sda5         198,387,712   198,776,831       389,120  83 Linux
 /dev/sda6         198,778,880   257,370,111    58,591,232  83 Linux
 /dev/sda7         257,372,160   272,994,303    15,622,144  82 Linux swap / Solaris
 /dev/sda8         272,996,352   282,759,167     9,762,816  83 Linux
 /dev/sda9         282,761,216   592,371,711   309,610,496  83 Linux


 "blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

 Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

 /dev/sda1        5232BD6832BD5229                       ntfs       SYSTEM_DRV
 /dev/sda2        DEEAC24EEAC2231F                       ntfs       Windows7_OS
 /dev/sda3        066EC8C06EC8AA2F                       ntfs       Lenovo_Recovery
 /dev/sda5        1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0   ext4       
 /dev/sda6        8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b   ext4       
 /dev/sda7        3512b57d-54a4-43ad-bbef-0fdb8b52a90b   swap       
 /dev/sda8        6ea3c7db-6797-4354-946d-d923c61812f0   ext4       
 /dev/sda9        607718a9-e715-4c3a-8a12-444d9ac2fb35   ext4       

 ================================ Mount points: =================================

 Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

 /dev/sda5        /boot                    ext4       (rw)
 /dev/sda6        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)
 /dev/sda8        /tmp                     ext4       (rw)
 /dev/sda9        /home                    ext4       (rw)


 ============================= sda5/grub/menu.lst: ==============================

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # menu.lst - See: grub(8), info grub, update-grub(8)
 #            grub-install(8), grub-floppy(8),
 #            grub-md5-crypt, /usr/share/doc/grub
 #            and /usr/share/doc/grub-legacy-doc/.

 ## default num
 # Set the default entry to the entry number NUM. Numbering starts from 0, and
 # the entry number 0 is the default if the command is not used.
 #
 # You can specify 'saved' instead of a number. In this case, the default entry
 # is the entry saved with the command 'savedefault'.
 # WARNING: If you are using dmraid do not use 'savedefault' or your
 # array will desync and will not let you boot your system.
 default        0

 ## timeout sec
 # Set a timeout, in SEC seconds, before automatically booting the default entry
 # (normally the first entry defined).
 timeout        3

 ## hiddenmenu
 # Hides the menu by default (press ESC to see the menu)
 hiddenmenu

 # Pretty colours
 color cyan/blue white/blue

 ## password ['--md5'] passwd
 # If used in the first section of a menu file, disable all interactive editing
 # control (menu entry editor and command-line)  and entries protected by the
 # command 'lock'
 # e.g. password topsecret
 #      password --md5 $1$gLhU0/$aW78kHK1QfV3P2b2znUoe/
 # password topsecret

 #
 # examples
 #
 # title        Windows 95/98/NT/2000
 # root     (hd0,0)
 # makeactive
 # chainloader  +1
 #
 # title        Linux
 # root     (hd0,1)
 # kernel   /vmlinuz root=/dev/hda2 ro
 #

 #
 # Put static boot stanzas before and/or after AUTOMAGIC KERNEL LIST

 ### BEGIN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
 ## lines between the AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST markers will be modified
 ## by the debian update-grub script except for the default options below

 ## DO NOT UNCOMMENT THEM, Just edit them to your needs

 ## ## Start Default Options ##
 ## default kernel options
 ## default kernel options for automagic boot options
 ## If you want special options for specific kernels use kopt_x_y_z
 ## where x.y.z is kernel version. Minor versions can be omitted.
 ## e.g. kopt=root=/dev/hda1 ro
 ##      kopt_2_6_8=root=/dev/hdc1 ro
 ##      kopt_2_6_8_2_686=root=/dev/hdc2 ro
 # kopt=root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro

 ## default grub root device
 ## e.g. groot=(hd0,0)
 # groot=1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0

 ## should update-grub create alternative automagic boot options
 ## e.g. alternative=true
 ##      alternative=false
 # alternative=true

 ## should update-grub lock alternative automagic boot options
 ## e.g. lockalternative=true
 ##      lockalternative=false
 # lockalternative=false

 ## additional options to use with the default boot option, but not with the
 ## alternatives
 ## e.g. defoptions=vga=791 resume=/dev/hda5
 # defoptions=quiet splash

 ## should update-grub lock old automagic boot options
 ## e.g. lockold=false
 ##      lockold=true
 # lockold=false

 ## Xen hypervisor options to use with the default Xen boot option
 # xenhopt=

 ## Xen Linux kernel options to use with the default Xen boot option
 # xenkopt=console=tty0

 ## altoption boot targets option
 ## multiple altoptions lines are allowed
 ## e.g. altoptions=(extra menu suffix) extra boot options
 ##      altoptions=(recovery) single
 # altoptions=(recovery mode) single

 ## controls how many kernels should be put into the menu.lst
 ## only counts the first occurence of a kernel, not the
 ## alternative kernel options
 ## e.g. howmany=all
 ##      howmany=7
 # howmany=all

 ## specify if running in Xen domU or have grub detect automatically
 ## update-grub will ignore non-xen kernels when running in domU and vice versa
 ## e.g. indomU=detect
 ##      indomU=true
 ##      indomU=false
 # indomU=detect

 ## should update-grub create memtest86 boot option
 ## e.g. memtest86=true
 ##      memtest86=false
 # memtest86=true

 ## should update-grub adjust the value of the default booted system
 ## can be true or false
 # updatedefaultentry=false

 ## should update-grub add savedefault to the default options
 ## can be true or false
 # savedefault=false

 ## ## End Default Options ##

 title      Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-27-generic
 uuid       1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
 kernel     /vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro quiet splash 
 initrd     /initrd.img-3.5.0-27-generic

 title      Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-27-generic (recovery mode)
 uuid       1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
 kernel     /vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro  single
 initrd     /initrd.img-3.5.0-27-generic

 title      Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-26-generic
 uuid       1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
 kernel     /vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro quiet splash 
 initrd     /initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic

 title      Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-26-generic (recovery mode)
 uuid       1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
 kernel     /vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro  single
 initrd     /initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic

 title      Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-17-generic
 uuid       1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
 kernel     /vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro quiet splash 
 initrd     /initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic

 title      Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-17-generic (recovery mode)
 uuid       1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
 kernel     /vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro  single
 initrd     /initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic

 title      Ubuntu 12.10, memtest86+
 uuid       1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
 kernel     /memtest86+.bin

 ### END DEBIAN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 ============================= sda5/grub/grub.cfg: ==============================

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 #
 # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
 #
 # It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
 # from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
 #

 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
 if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
   set have_grubenv=true
   load_env
 fi
 set default="0"

 if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
   menuentry_id_option="--id"
 else
   menuentry_id_option=""
 fi

 export menuentry_id_option

 if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
   set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
   save_env saved_entry
   set prev_saved_entry=
   save_env prev_saved_entry
   set boot_once=true
 fi

 function savedefault {
   if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
     saved_entry="${chosen}"
     save_env saved_entry
   fi
 }

 function recordfail {
   set recordfail=1
   if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
 }

 function load_video {
   if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
     insmod all_video
   else
     insmod efi_gop
     insmod efi_uga
     insmod ieee1275_fb
     insmod vbe
     insmod vga
     insmod video_bochs
     insmod video_cirrus
   fi
 }

 if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
    font=unicode
 else
 insmod part_msdos
 insmod ext2
 set root='hd0,msdos6'
 if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b
 else
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b
 fi
     font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
 fi

 if loadfont $font ; then
   set gfxmode=auto
   load_video
   insmod gfxterm
   set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
   set lang=en_US
   insmod gettext
 fi
 terminal_output gfxterm
 if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set timeout=-1
 else
   set timeout=5
 fi
 ### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
 set menu_color_normal=white/black
 set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
 if background_color 44,0,30; then
   clear
 fi
 ### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
 function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
 }
 if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
   if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
     if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
       if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
         set linux_gfx_mode=keep
       else
         set linux_gfx_mode=text
       fi
     else
       set linux_gfx_mode=text
     fi
   else
     set linux_gfx_mode=keep
   fi
 else
   set linux_gfx_mode=text
 fi
 export linux_gfx_mode
 if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
 menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b' {
 recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
    fi
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-27-generic
 }
 submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-27-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-27-generic-advanced-8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b' {
    recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-27-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-27-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-27-generic-recovery-8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b' {
    recordfail
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-27-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-26-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-26-generic-advanced-8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b' {
    recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-26-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-26-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-26-generic-recovery-8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b' {
    recordfail
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-26-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-advanced-8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b' {
    recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-recovery-8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b' {
    recordfail
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
 }

 ### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

 ### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
 menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
    fi
    linux16 /memtest86+.bin
 }
 menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0
    fi
    linux16 /memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
 }
 ### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
 menuentry 'Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-5232BD6832BD5229' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  5232BD6832BD5229
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5232BD6832BD5229
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
 }
 menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-DEEAC24EEAC2231F' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  DEEAC24EEAC2231F
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root DEEAC24EEAC2231F
    fi
    chainloader +1
 }
 ### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
 ### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
 # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
 # menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
 # the 'exec tail' line above.
 ### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
 if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
   source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
 elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
   source $prefix/custom.cfg;
 fi
 ### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 =================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

            GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

                =                grub/grub.cfg                                  1
                =                grub/menu.lst                                  1
                =                initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic                    4
                =                initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic                    6
                =                initrd.img-3.5.0-27-generic                    2
                =                vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic                       1
                =                vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic                       3
                =                vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic                       1

 =============================== sda6/etc/fstab: ================================

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
 #
 # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
 # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
 # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
 #
 # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
 # / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
 UUID=8a9c42e0-a5a2-493f-ac7c-f697567e7c8b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
 # /boot was on /dev/sda5 during installation
 UUID=1e06333b-052f-4dc6-905e-d4617d6436e0 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
 # /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
 UUID=607718a9-e715-4c3a-8a12-444d9ac2fb35 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
 # /tmp was on /dev/sda8 during installation
 UUID=6ea3c7db-6797-4354-946d-d923c61812f0 /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
 # swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
 UUID=3512b57d-54a4-43ad-bbef-0fdb8b52a90b none            swap    sw              0       0
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 =================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

            GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

                =                initrd.img                                     2
                =                initrd.img.old                                 2
                =                vmlinuz                                        1
                =                vmlinuz.old                                    1

 =============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
 awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
```